# Create an in-memory FileDescriptor

Tags: java, android, file-descriptor, bytearrayoutputstream, bytearrayinputstream

[FileDescriptor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileDescriptor.html) API in Android says:

> Instances of the file descriptor class serve as an opaque handle to
>   the underlying machine-specific structure representing an open file,
>   an open socket, or another source or sink of bytes.

I want to create a FileDescriptor object using [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) and [ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)

Also, FileDescriptor is a final class and cannot be overridden. The only constructor it has says -

> Constructs an **(invalid)** FileDescriptor object.

Any idea how to use FileDescriptor in Android?

***EDIT***

I want to use it in [MediaMuxer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html#MediaMuxer(java.io.FileDescriptor,%20int)). Instead of writing to a file, I want to have the media data in-memory and copy it to a TCP socket for live streaming. So my FileDescriptor should be a "sink of bytes."

Comment: where do you want to return that `FileDescriptor` from? from a `ContentProvider`?

Comment: Use `ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe()` and kin, though I'm not sure it's going to do what you want it to.

Comment: I want to use it in `MediaMuxer (FileDescriptor fd, int format)` and so that I can write the bytes to output stream of a TCP socket without writing the data to a file.

Comment: then use `ParcelFileDescriptor#fromSocket()` method

Comment: #fromSocket() did not work for me. `E/MPEG4Writer: cannot seek mFd: Illegal seek (29) 47` OutputStream of TCP socket cannot be seeked. So looking for another solution that involves ByteArrayOutputStream with FileDescriptor.

Comment: so try what @CommonsWare said: create a pipe, but i think you will get the same `"cannot seek mFd"` error - i believe that only physical file is "seekable"

Comment: @PC. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @mh taquia No. I didn't.

Comment: @PC. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LocalSocket`, but be careful because there are security implications.

`LocalSocket` is the Android API for working with Unix Domain Sockets. Domain Sockets are similar to TCP/IP sockets except that they only exist on the device, they cannot be used for communication across a network.

A simple, but insecure solution to your problem is as follows:

```java
// Create a unique name for the socket.
String name = "your.package.name-" + UUID.randomUUID();

// Bind a server to the socket.
final LocalServerSocket server = new LocalServerSocket(name);

// Connect a client to the socket.
LocalSocket client = new LocalSocket(LocalSocket.SOCKET_STREAM);
client.connect(new LocalSocketAddress(name, LocalSocketAddress.Namespace.ABSTRACT));

// Start a thread to read from the server socket.
new Thread(new Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        LocalSocket socket = server.accept();

        // To read data sent by the client, read from socket.getInputStream().
        // To send data to the client, write to socket.getOutputStream().

        // After you are done you will need to call socket.close().
    }
}).start();

// Get the FileDescriptor associated with the client.
// You can use this FileDescriptor to write data to and/or read data
// sent from the server.
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = client.getFileDescriptor();

// After you are done you will need to call server.close() and client.close().
```

This creates a socket in the abstract socket namespace. This is insecure because domain sockets are system-wide and sockets in the abstract namespace are not restricted by any permissions system. The only requirement to connect or bind to a name in the abstract namespace is to know the name, and the socket name used by your app can be easily discovered by an attacker through decompilation. There is also a possibility that another app may use the same socket name by accident. So another app could intercept your data, or send unexpected data through the socket, and it is difficult to guard against this.

A better, but more complicated solution is to create a socket in the filesystem namespace. The API to do this is super weird, but it can be achieved as follows:

```java
// Create a unique name for the socket in your app's private data area.
// Note this example creates a file named like socket-xxxx in the root of
// your app's private data area. You might want to put it in a subdirectory.
String name = context
    .getFileStreamPath("socket-" + UUID.randomUUID())
    .getAbsolutePath();
LocalSocketAddress address = new LocalSocketAddress(name, LocalSocketAddress.Namespace.FILESYSTEM);

// Bind a server to the socket.
LocalSocket server = new LocalSocket(LocalSocket.SOCKET_STREAM);
server.bind(address);
final LocalServerSocket serverWrapper = new LocalServerSocket(server.getFileDescriptor());

// Connect a client to the socket.
LocalSocket client = new LocalSocket(LocalSocket.SOCKET_STREAM);
client.connect(address);

// Start a thread to read from the server socket.
new Thread(new Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        LocalSocket socket = serverWrapper.accept();

        // To read data sent by the client, read from socket.getInputStream().
        // To send data to the client, write to socket.getOutputStream().

        // After you are done you will need to call socket.close() and
        // serverWrapper.close().
    }
}).start();

// Get the FileDescriptor associated with the client.
// You can use this FileDescriptor to write data to and/or read data
// sent from the server.
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = client.getFileDescriptor();

// After you are done you will need to call server.close() and client.close().
```

This does create a file on the filesystem, but none of the data that passes through the socket is ever written to disk, it is entirely in-memory. The file is just a name that represents the socket, similar to the files in `/dev` that represent devices. Because the socket is accessed through the filesystem, it is subject to the usual filesystem permissions, so it is easy to restrict access to the socket by placing the socket in your app's private data area.

Since this technique creates a file on the filesystem, it would be a good idea to delete the file after you're done, and also perhaps to check for and clean up old sockets every so often, in case your app crashes and leaves old files laying around.

Answer (score 1):

As of Android R(30), you can and it works with MediaMuxer!

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/Os#memfd_create(java.lang.String,%20int)

```
private FileDescriptor getFileDescriptor(Context context) throws IOException, ErrnoException{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        return Os.memfd_create("thumb", 0);
    } else {
        return new FileOutputStream(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "thumb.heif")).getFD();
    }
}
private void mux() {
    MediaMuxer mediaMuxer = new MediaMuxer(getFileDescriptor(context), MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_HEIF);
    // Muxing code omitted
    mediaMuxer.stop();
    StructStat structStat = Os.fstat(fileDescriptor);
    bytes = new byte[(int)structStat.st_size];
    Os.lseek(fileDescriptor, 0, OsConstants.SEEK_SET);
    Os.read(fileDescriptor, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    mediaMuxer.release();
```

FYI:  In theory you should have been able as of Oreo using:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager#openProxyFileDescriptor(int,%20android.os.ProxyFileDescriptorCallback,%20android.os.Handler)

For some reason MediaMuxer blows chunks with the FileDescriptor created in this way.  I've used it in other places and it worked fine.

Comment: It works with `FileOutputStream` but not with `ByteArrayOutputStream`

Comment: Correct.  The FileOutputStream was just a backwards compatible way to get a FileDescriptor pre Android-R.  For Android-R+ the code uses a memory base FileDescriptor which is compatible with MediaMuxer.  I assume MediaMuxer requires random access, which is why it doesn't support OutputStreams.

Answer (score -1):

You can redirect System.out to ByteArrayOutputStream
and use FileDescriptor.out as filedescriptor

```
ByteArrayOutputStream buff = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream old = System.out;
System.setOut(new PrintStream(buff));

... use FileDescriptor.out ...

System.setOut(old);
System.out.println(new String(buff.toByteArray()));
```